# django - Import models from legacy databaseI

Tags: python, django, database

I already have a database that I would like to use in my new Django project. I used the `inspectdb > models.py` command to get the models from my old database, but I get the following error:

```
from django.db import models
# Unable to inspect table '>'
# The error was: (1146, "Table 'colta.>' doesn't exist")
# Unable to inspect table 'Grupa/models.py'
# The error was: (1146, "Table 'colta.grupa/models.py' doesn't exist")
```

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with the command.  Did you already test `python manage inspectdb` without the trailing `> models.py`?
That way you can get the model to standard output and check if it constructs the models or if there is no connection with the database.

Comment: It actually connects to the databases, and shows me all of the classes in the console. Should I just copy-paste it into models.py? :D

Comment: Yes, do it.  Maybe it is not the best solution, but it actually lets you test the models.  Be careful with the indentation.

Comment: Are you using windows?